# How to add post processing options when using youtube-dl in a python script

Tags: python, youtube-dl

How to add post-processing options equivalent of --embed-thumbnails and --add-metadata when using youtube-dl in a python script?

I read the following documentation, but couldn't find post processing 'key value' options.
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl

Answer (score 6):

The full list of options is documented [in `YoutubeDL.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312). If you only want to replicate command-line options, you can also have a look in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L286).

To replicate `--embed-thumbnail` and `--add-metadata`, use the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'writethumbnail': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegMetadata'
    }, {
        'key': 'EmbedThumbnail',
        'already_have_thumbnail': True,  # overwrite any thumbnails already present
    }],
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Comment: I need to add metadata not subtitles, so I used `code`                      
     ydl_opts = {
    'format': '140',
    'postprocessors': [
        {'key': 'FFmpegMetadata',},
        {'key': 'EmbedThumbnail',
         'already_have_thumbnail': True,}],
    'outtmpl': '%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
    } `code` but it gives following error 
  youtube_dl\postprocessor\embedthumbnail.py", line 36, in run
    thumbnail_filename = info['thumbnails'][-1]['filename']

Comment: KeyError: u'filename` **missed this line in my above comment**

Comment: Oops, changed to use metadata, not thumbnails. Does the new code work for you? It runs for me without any problem. Your error seems to be related to thumbnail embedding, which you don't want, or do you after all?

Comment: Still your code is for subtitle, isn't it? I need metadata and thumbnail (no subtitle required)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Updated again. You'll get an error if you enable just the postprocessor but do not the actual thumbnail extraction.

Comment: It is working, but I think it doesn't call ffmpeg exe for post processing, i.e. the thumbnail images are not merged to m4a files and no metadata added.

Comment: How are you extracting the thumbnail? For me, with `AtomicParsley youtube-dl\ test\ video\ \'\'_ä↭-BaW_jenozKc.mp4 -E` I can extract a JPEG file of the thumbnail. Maybe your system is missing AtomicParsley? That, and not ffmpeg, is used to embed the thumbnail.

Comment: No, AtomicParsley is installed and working with youtubde-dl command line options, but not working with a python code given in phihag's example

Comment: Does it work if you use the youtube-dl command-line? And again, how are you testing that there is no thumbnail?

Comment: When I used youtube-dl in a command line, the downloaded audio file icon is a thumbnail, but while using the given script (run by python script.py) the thumbnail is downloaded as a jpg file to the same folder. It seems that the post-processing not done. Also, I checked meta tags using AtomicParsley which returns an error saying no metatag.

Comment: [Here is a Dockerfile](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/phihag/6371540e59cccc14df847e1cfa747692/raw/27828bbdc8b08619933062b1411fbc01fab5f329/Dockerfile) that runs the code in this answer in a docker container. Can you verify that, yes, on your machine this works too? If so, do you see any difference between the docker system and your system?

Comment: Sorry, i am using a windows 7. I will try the code in linux

Comment: It should work on Windows fine too, but then make sure that there are no problems with encodings (on Windows, these are frequently misconfigured), and that both AtomicParseley and ffmpeg are in the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).